# New Node User Opening Channels Through Zap

Tags: lightning-network, full-node, ln-opening-channels, ln-channel-balance-management, zap

I recently set up my first node and connected through Zap. I currently have one channel open which is funded on my local side and on the remote side for a small amount. I was told that my node is not public and I cannot find it on 1ml. Does anyone know what I need to fix this?

I used the Strike app to create the remote funding by sending my Strike account some BTC from Zap. Ideally I would like to have a channel with about $500 capacity with the end goal of using Strike to buy BTC. To do this would I send $1000 of BTC to my Zap wallet, fund the channel on the local side with $500 worth, then send the other $500 worth to my Strike account - creating $500 local and remote funding on that channel?

An additional question I have: How do I set up a smaller channel that is fully public and will see activity so I can participate in the network and earn lightning fees?

Appreciate any help.